# Issues with mDNS on an Android device

Tags: browser, dns

I'm running a local testing environment (MAMP) on a Mac (Mountain Lion), and Im having having difficulty accessing these sites on my Galaxy S3 running 4.1.2

Everything works fine testing using windows laptops, iphones etc ... on the network, except the android device does not recognise the name of the machine (mDNS)

There is a work around by using the machines IP address but this has its problems and isn't an ideal solution.

Is there a solution I could use to get mDNS working on the mobiles browsers?

Cheers

Comment: Is this a development question? Are you trying to use the zeroconf APIs from Android?

Comment: Im testing websites hosted on my Mac

Comment: Have you tried both the bare hostname of your machine, and the fully qualified domain name? I find most mobile devices (including non-Android ones) don't resolve the hosts on my local network unless I use their fully qualified name.

Comment: @GAThrawn I'm not sure that I know the difference between the two? I use 'compname-imac.local'

Comment: You might need to try the IP instead -- unless the nameserver your DHCP server (on WiFi) offers can resolve your local hosts. This domain for sure won't work via 3G, as your provider will certainly *not* resolve your local names ;)

Comment: @noelmcg In that case it sounds like you're already using the FQDN (bare hostname would just be `compname-imac`).

Comment: Using the IP is be a bit of a pain Izzy, as it isn't fixed, and I'll also have probs with things on the local environment, like wordpress multisite, typekit etc ... @GAThrawn thanks for the clarification, can you use a FQDN on an android device on a local network?

Comment: See newer question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230644/22600